# Java: How can I get the size of Integer(object) array?

Tags: java, integer

I'm talking about `Integer` object data type, not primitive `int`

Suppose this:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[5];
    arr[0] = 2;
    arr[1] = 2;
    arr[2] = 3;
```

Then the array will look like this `{2,2,3,null,null}`

How can I get the size of the array? In this case, the size is 5

Comment: The same way as with any other array: `arr.lehgth`.

Comment: `null` is a default element value for all arrays of objects.

Comment: I flagged this question as favorite because I misread it. I thought the question was on *how much memory (in bytes)* would be used. How would this be done?

Answer (score 5):

Same way as for any other array - you use the `length` field:

```
int length = arr.length; // 5
```

From the [JLS section 10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - The public final field `length`, which contains the number of components of the array. length may be positive or zero.
> - ...

If you want to count the non-null values, you'd use something like:

```
int count = 0;
for (Integer value : arr) {
    if (value != null) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

(I'm sure there's a clever way to do this in fewer lines using the streams API in Java 8, but let's keep it simple for now...)

Comment: he initialized 5 elements though, won't this return 5? I think he's asking for how to determine how many elements are not null.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: I don't think so - look at the question: "In this case, the size is 5"

Comment: @SnakeDoc Agreeing with the Skeetmeister here. The phrasing of the question seems to indicate that OP is interested in *all members*, null or not.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks! I will accept your answer in 7 minutes